# Incrementing a variable in NASM

Tags: nasm

I'm trying to write a NASM program that flips through a matrix and sums all the number.

I've been stuck for the last two hours trying to get an increment operation to work.

I tried

```
mov DX, 0
inc DX
```

and

```
mov DX, DX+1
```

and

```
mov CX, counter    ; a variable initialized to 0
inc CX
```

and more but NOTHING is working.

Please help me !

**update**

Specifically, I'm getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: i386 architecture of input file `a3.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
a3.o: In function `main':
a3.asm:(.text+0x18): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.bss'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It seems the issue isn't related to the inc operation but to some "bad" file you linked against (namely a3.o) can you share the source of a3.asm ?

Comment: You can't really do something like `mov DX, DX+1`, unless `DX` is a compile-time constant declared in the source. This is not a high-level language : you need to use CPU instructions for practically *everything* you do at runtime. Also, zeroing out a register on x86 is usually done with XORing it with itself. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 32 bits / 64 bits mismatch.

For a 32 bits executable do:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o main.o main.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -o main main.o
```

For a 64 bits executable do:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o main.o main.asm
ld [-m elf_x86_64] -o main main.o
```

To link with gcc replace the second command with:

```
gcc -m32 -o main main.o      # 32 bits
gcc [-m64] -o main main.o    # 64 bits
```

The stuff in square brackets is not strictly necessary.

Comment: I use gcc, which you don't mention. What is `gcc` compared to `ld`?

Comment: +1, accepted. THanks!  Can you briefly explain what the line `nasm -f...` and waht the line `ld -m elf_....` are doing?